# ¿Cómo podría comparar si el valor de una variable existe en un array? PHP

Tags: javascript, php

estoy intentando hacer que a través de un condicional de tipo

```
if (in_array($fp_get, $bl_a_fp )) {}
```

Ejecute una acción en caso de que el contenido de la variable `$fp_get` se encuentre en el array de `$bl_a_fp`. El problema es que el código que he hecho no hace nada.
Dejo aquí el code. Un saludo.

**Código Actualizado**

Código de index.php:

```
 var fpPromises = import("https://openfpcdn.io/fingerprintjs/v3")
        .then(FingerprintJS => FingerprintJS.load())

    fpPromises
        .then(fp => fp.get())
        .then(result => {
            const visitorId = result.visitorId;
            localStorage.setItem('primary_fp', visitorId);
          //  console.log(visitorId);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./assets/php/honeypot_blacklist.php",
                data: { visitorId: visitorId  }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                console.log("Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg);
            });


});
```

Código PHP (honeypot_blacklist.php):

```
    $fp_get = $_POST['visitorId'];
    $bl_a_fp = [

"718b50432ab82e4cdd2c0456acecf2c7", "14b6b10688e02e9b3e6e99b5564a6c81", "83972b892a43fc838019058cc1948c05", "3723491ffeb95b9c550c372bfb13c62d"


];




if (in_array($fp_get, $bl_a_fp )) {

        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.natural-environment.com/"/>'; exit();

}
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor provee un ejemplo del error que te causa y que esperas que pase.

Comment: Hola @Excorpion he añadido un trozo de código que se me había olvidado.
Lo que me gustaría hacer es que si detecta que el valor de la fingerprint está en el array del blacklist, se le redirija a google.
Y error como tal, no me origina ninguno, solo que no cumple la función, no sé por qué.

Comment: Ok estás aplicando mal las cosas... la variable `$fp_get` contiene un string, que no se encuentra en tu lista.

Comment: La cosa es que en teoría debería de estarlo, pues añadí en la lista el fingerprint de mi ordenador.
Con la variable `$fp_get` hago una call al DOM Storage en la que está incluida el valor de mi fingerprint

Comment: Pero si haces un var_dump() de `$fp_get` que obtienes ?? Ponlo en el post.

Comment: Tal como lo tienes, la cadena $fp_get solo contiene un string, que es el "<script type="text/javascript"... Eso, cuando estas evaluando el php, queda como cadena, NO SE EJECUTA. Por ello, cuando vas a comparar el in_array es una cadena, y no te va a entrar en el if. Me da que esperas que se ejecute el javascript y te genere un valor, y luego quieres compararlo en el in_array, pero eso no funciona asi

Comment: si quieres hacer algo como eso, vas a tener que usar ajax

Comment: Por medio de ajax como menciona Jakala, es como le pasas la variable a PHP.

Comment: Entiendo, voy a mirar a ver qué puedo hacer.
Cualquier cosa os digo

Comment: Estoy probando, pero la redirección que me gustaría que hiciese, no la hace.
Muestra lo siguiente en la consola:
`Los datos que se recibieron: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.natural-environment.com/"/>`
Actualizo el código en la pregunta.

Comment: Tu código está funcionando bien. El servidor te devuelve esto precisamente: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.natural-environment.com/"/>`. Lo que no entiendo es por qué quieres redigir ¿? o por qué mandas a buscar una etiqueta `meta` al servidor ¿? ¿? ¿? Al servidor se mandan a buscar cosas que están en el servidor. Y generalmente con Ajax no hace falta redirigir (aunque se puede también), pues puedes actualizar la página del cliente sin tener que ir a otro sitio, o puedes llamar a otro codigo del servidor si fuera necesario. Explica qué justifica aquí una redirección.

Comment: @A.Cedano debido a que estoy haciendo un "sistema de seguridad" a través de Fingerprint, debido a que últimamente he notado que algunos usuarios con misma fingerprint pero distinta IP han intentado vulnerar mi página web.
Es por eso que quiero evitarlos a toda costa, que justo cuando accedan a la web les envíe a otro lado

Comment: Entendido. Entonces, si las verificaciones se hacen del lado del servidor, usando PHP, puedes redirigir en el `done` de tu petición Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que he leído y visto, tu código funciona bien, al menos la lógica se cumple.

Donde veo el problema es el parte del frontend, que es ahí donde debería hacerse la re-dirección.

Te sugiero lo siguiente para el `index.php` en la parte del Javascript(método done del ajax):

```javascript
 var fpPromises = import("https://openfpcdn.io/fingerprintjs/v3")
        .then(FingerprintJS => FingerprintJS.load())

    fpPromises
        .then(fp => fp.get())
        .then(result => {
            const visitorId = result.visitorId;
            localStorage.setItem('primary_fp', visitorId);
          //  console.log(visitorId);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./assets/php/honeypot_blacklist.php",
                data: { visitorId: visitorId  }
            }).done(function (response) {//siempre recomiendo pasa un objeto mas complejo que simplemente pasar un string

                console.log(response);//veamos que trae de vuelta el request
                
                if (response.isForbidden) {
                    //nunca habia probado este método de redireccion
                    var meta = document.createElement('meta');
                    meta.httpEquiv = "refresh";
                    meta.content = "0";
                    meta.url= "http://www.natural-environment.com/";
                    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);

                   //o también simplemente puedes hacer el redirect
                   window.location.href = "http://www.natural-environment.com/";
                   
                } else {
                    //No pasa nada si está permitido
                }

            });

});
```

Y para el `honeypot_blacklist.php`:

```php
<?php

    $fp_get = $_POST['visitorId'];
    $bl_a_fp = [
                  "718b50432ab82e4cdd2c0456acecf2c7", 
                  "83972b892a43fc838019058cc1948c05", 
                  "3723491ffeb95b9c550c372bfb13c62d"
    ];


$response = [];//Array responsable de pasar datos al frontend

if (in_array($fp_get, $bl_a_fp )) {// Si Fingerprint esta en Black List se prohibe el acceso
       $response = ['isForbidden' => true, 'msg' => 'Acceso prohibido'];
} else {
       $response = ['isForbidden' => false, 'msg' => 'Acceso permitido'];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Espero que te sirva como guía.

PD: El código no ha sido probado,lo escribí directamente en la respuesta.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Por preferencia, haría la redirección directa, sin la etiqueta `meta`, incluso si se muestra un mensaje (probablemente en ventana modal) y se redirija después de cierto tiempo, optaría por un temporizador (`setTimeout()`). De todos modos... +1

Comment: Gracias, funciona de lujo